# XmlSchemaInfo.SchemaElement is null after validation with reciving PVSI

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml, xsd-validation

I try to validate XDocument with compiled (and correct) schema set and with providing post validation schema info (PVSI):

```
public void ValidateDoc(XDocument doc)
{
    if (doc == null)
        return;

    // _schema is correct filled schema-set
    if (!_schemas.IsCompiled)
        _schemas.Compile();

    try
    {
        _validated.Clear();
        if (_schemas.Count > 0)
            doc.Validate(_schemas, OnValidate, true);

        foreach (var item in _validated)
        {
            var si = item.GetSchemaInfo();
            // si exists and si.Validity is set to XmlSchemaValidity.Invalid but si.SchemaElement and si.SchemaAttribute is null
        }
    }
    catch (XmlSchemaException err)
    {
        _log.FatalException(string.Format("Failed to validate document {0} [{1}, {2}] ", doc.BaseUri, err.LineNumber, err.LinePosition), err);
    }
}

protected virtual void OnValidate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
{
    if (ValidationEvent != null)
        ValidationEvent(sender, args);

    var xobj = sender as XObject;
    if (xobj != null)
    {
        xobj.AddAnnotation(new XmlErrInfo(args));
        if (xobj is XElement)
            _validated.Add((XElement)xobj);
    }
}
```

But .GetSchemaInfo().SchemaElement is null (and other fields its empty too), instead of point to compiled schema element (I need to use it in future validation scenarios of same elements). What's wrong with it or what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you wanted to access the `SchemaElement` of valid elements I could understand your approach but you seem to want to access the `SchemaElement` of those invalid elements reported to the event handler. I don't think those properties are populated for invalid nodes.

Comment: You're right! `SchemaElement` is published in the case when node is valid